# How to organize data in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'd like to organize the dataset (A) to look like (B). 
I have used transpose as shown in c but it didn't organize the data as shown in B. Any hint will be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Highlight one column of vertical data and copy it. Put the cursor where you want the new row to begin, right click, and select "Paste special..." Tick the transpose box at the bottom of the dialogue and click OK.

Comment: @P Fitz        Thanks for your help. I have tried Transpose (C) but it didn't organize the data in the way I want as shown in B.